# Find Maclaurin series given some derivatives

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be a function that has derivatives of all orders on the open interval $(2.5, 3.5)$. Assume that $f(3)=7$, $f'(3)=−3$, $f''(3)=12$ and
$|f'''(x)≤36|$ for all $x$ in the interval $(2.5, 3.5)$.

Let $h(x)$ be a function that has the properties $h(3)=−2$ and $h'(x)=f (x)$. Find the Maclaurin series for $h(x)$. (Write as many non-zero terms as possible).

Would the series simply be $-2+7(x-3)-\frac{3}{2!}(x-3)^2+\frac{12}{3!}(x-3)^3+...$?

I think that there is a mistake here. A Maclaurin series is centered about $x=0$, so how is it possible to find such a series with only information about $x=3$?

**Disclaimer**

This is a homework assignment that I think might have a mistake in it. I am not asking for the answer, but instead to know if there is a mistake. If there is no mistake, then I would like to know why not.

Comment: The problem also mentions the interval $(2.5,3.5)$ so that leads me to believe that it's a typo.

Comment: A Taylor series can be centered anywhere, not just at $x=0$. The interval is appropriate, $|x-3| < {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat But the given question mentions Maclaurin, not Taylor.

Comment: @AndrewLi, that interval was for a different part of the problem with a Lagrange error bound. I don’t think it’s necessarily in this part of it that I posted.

Comment: Taylor, Mclaurin, they are the same.

Comment: If the function is not defined at $x=0$ then you cannot develop a Taylor series around that point.

Comment: @copper.hat, so are you saying that yes, there is a mistake?

Comment: I would presume that the question meant the Taylor series around $x=3$. I tend to view Taylor and Maclaurin series as the same thing, so I would interpret the question as finding the Taylor series for $h$. You should really ask your instructor though.